# Passing struct via Qt SIGNAL/SLOT works with Qt5 but with Qt4 ... (function signature issue)

Tags: c++, qt

The following substitution was made while porting an app from Qt5 to Qt4:

```
connect(_database, &Database::data, this, &DataProvider::store);
```

became:

```
connect(_database, SIGNAL(data(ParameterData)), this, SLOT(store(Database::ParameterData)));
```

The SIGNAL and the SLOT arguments format was given by auto-completition in QtCreator.

It compiles but gives the following when executed:

```
QObject::connect: Incompatible sender/receiver arguments
        Database::data(ParameterData) --> DataProvider::store(Database::ParameterData)
```

Which suggests me to modifies it to:

```
connect(_database, SIGNAL(data(Database::ParameterData)), this, SLOT(store(Database::ParameterData)));
```

Again, it comiles. But now gives:

```
Object::connect: No such signal Database::data(Database::ParameterData) in ..\plot\src\dataprovider.cpp:13
```

In fact, the SIGNAL signature is:

```
void data(ParameterData data);
```

And the issue is actually solved by modifying the SIGNAL signature to:

```
void data(Database::ParameterData data);
```

I tried one alternative approach, modify SLOT's signature to:

```
void store(ParameterData pd);
```

and make the connections this way:

```
connect(_database, SIGNAL(data(ParameterData)), this, SLOT(store(ParameterData)));
```

Now it doesn't even compile, compiler gives:

```
error: 'ParameterData' has not been declared
 void store(ParameterData pd);
            ^
```

Would it be possible to go through the alternative way?

Comment: You can use `using Database::ParameterData` to get rid of `Database::` in the slot's signature, but I don't know why would you want that. Double-check that the signal and slot accept a parameter of the same class (you don't have two classes named `ParameterData`, do you?)

Comment: I think this happens because the SLOT and SIGNAL macros require the same function signature(this is just a conjecture I've made after months working with Qt4), a using directive would probably solve it, no idea if there's a better way

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall, I tried `using Database::ParameterData;` but compiler says `Database is not a namespace` (?). And for the motivation of it I'll say, it makes the connection smaller (more elegant?). And NO, off course there aren't two `ParameterData` classes :)

Comment: You could just use `Database::ParameterData` wherever you need to pass an argument of that type.